# Why do Jewish funeral homes tend to be the main supplier of Jewish calendars?

Tags: minhag, history, calendar, cemetery-grave, publications

Perhaps, this question is too "trivial". It seems that Jewish funeral homes tend to be the primary "printer" and supplier of Jewish calendars. For decades, many yeshivot as well as shuls get the large colorful calendars from Jewish funeral homes.

Yes, I do get smaller calendars in the mail from the numerous yeshivot and other charity orgs that love to flood my mailbox this time of year. But, as stated, these are usually small "pocket" calendars and they are rarely as colorful and large like the "funeral" calendars.

Someone in shul joked, "It's not as if my grandma who died 20 years ago needs to know when Yom Kippur is this year!" There's both truth and some falsehood to that statement, but the question is why, how, and when funeral homes got involved in this "business"?

It does seem somewhat odd, in a sense. Their business is mainly handling the dead, whereas a calendar is more important for the living. I would think that a Judaica store or a shul should be the main printer and supplier of free calendars. As a matter of fact, perhaps they should supply these calendars to the funeral home, not the other way around.

Comment: This seems to be dependent on locale. I just got a full-size colorful calendar in the mail... from the town council.

Comment: @Scimonster I've seen this in at least three cities in the US, FWIW. I would expect that how communities work in Israel and outside would be significantly different, since in Israel, various levels of government participate directly in the Jewish communal infrastructure.

Comment: It's just advertising. They want their name conveniently hanging on the wall when the moment that people never seem to plan for suddenly happens.

Comment: That is not necessarily true in Houston, I can't remember the last time I got a calendar from a Jewish Funeral Home here.  Most of the calendars I get are either from Jewish charities in general or local stores that cater to the Houston Jewish Community.

Comment: Chabad here sends out very large, colorful calendars. But I do agree that this seems to also be a regular thing for funeral homes to supply.

Comment: Interesting question @Dan. In Brooklyn, it is 100% true. Even some synagogues distribute funeral home calandra

Answer (score 6):

A calendar is important for the dead - this way the living can figure out when their Yarzheit is, and say Kaddish and learn as a Zechus for the Neshama.

Comment: Good point! For many Jews, Yahrtzeits are the main impetus, other than certain holidays, for having any awareness of the Jewish calendar.

Comment: Boy, I feel somewhat "dumbified" by missing a pretty obvious answer!

Comment: True, but this seems like more of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Those who care will either already know or will look it up. Those who don't won't. So this doesn't seem like a good rationale (FWIW, I keep a calendar on my Mac, I set it to show the AM dates in addition to CE and download the rest from Hebcal every few years.) I like a physical calendar for finding licht-bentschen for Shabbat and chaggim.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Don't you need a calendar to look it up?

Comment: I think that @NoachmiFrankfurt is raising a good point. No calendar states anyone's Yahrtzeit date. (Perhaps, there are some that state Moshe Rabbeinu's yahrtzeit, and I think Chaba"d ones may indicate yahrtzeits of all their past rebbe'im.) So, one would already have to know their relative's Hebrew yahrtzeit date beforehand.

Comment: @DanF: However often people do not know when the Hebrew date will come out on the English calendar. Thus they need the calendar to match up the dates.

Comment: Gershon, for that, most schuls, yeshivot, and some websites will provide that information just as easily, IMO.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: Is it not easier to have the info in your home?

Comment: It still doesn't say why the funeral homes are the major producer of luchot (at list in the NYC and Boston areas).

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, Funeral homes' giving out of calendars predates widespread use of the web, and many more people observe Yahrtzeits but don't frequent shuls or yeshivot.

Comment: @IsaacMoses and others (I can only "ping" one person) - A few hours after I posted the question, I spoke to a Jewish co-worker and asked him this. He has attended a few Catholic funerals in the past, and noticed that Catholic funeral homes also publish calendars (I didn't ask him if they include the Judaic dates, so Catholics know about Jewish yahrtzeits ... Hey, why not?) So, as Mr. msh210 indicated below, this is not a uniquely Jewish activity. We're imitating Gentiles, or they imitate us. Not sure who was first. I'm biased - I think we were!

Answer (score 2):

[A search online shows that funeral homes' giving out calendars is not a Jewish thing.](//www.google.com/search?q=%22free+calendar%22+%22funeral+home%7cparlor%7cparlour%22+OR+mortuary) (And [the question of why funeral homes in general give out calendars is off-topic on this site](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=7962626#7962626).)